# Using \dots inside replacement text of \edef seems to break the \dots macro for later use

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have come across a strange issue in LaTeX, as seen in the minimal example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
% 1: (\dots)

\edef\sameasdots{\dots}
2: (\sameasdots)

3: (\dots)
\end{document}
```

which gives the output

> 2: (...)
> 3: (.)

Using the macro \sameasdots breaks the \dots macro, which afterwards displays only a single dot.

But if I uncomment line 3, i.e. use \dots before \sameasdots at least once, the issue does not appear. It only happens in conjunction with \edef, not \def, so an obvious workaround would be to use \def instead. But I need \edef because in my use case I'm defining macros in a for-loop which provides the replacement text as a macro, which has to be replaced on definition.

Does anybody have an idea what causes this behavior and whether it is a bug? I'm using pdfLaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\protected@edef` instead of `\edef`, see http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-edef for more details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
 1: (\dots)

\makeatletter
\protected@edef\sameaasdots{\dots}
\makeatother
2: (\sameaasdots)

3: (\dots)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent! I found another solution myself using copious amounts of \expandafters to replace the \edef, but this is clearly the proper way.